# Causes of: com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: Exited with code: 1

Tags: macos, mac, launchd, bundle, quarantine

A subset of our users are reporting that our application refuses to run (bounces once in the dock, and then closes).

If we drill into the application bundle (`/Application.app/Contents/MacOS`) and execute the app from there (`./Application`), it runs fine. So the problem is with the bundle, not the binary.

Looking at the permissions for the bundle (`ls -l | grep "Application.app"`), we see something like the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 user staff 102 Dec 2 15:10 Application.app
```

Looking at the extended attribute, we can see the following:

```
com.apple.quarantine     61
```

So we remove the quarantine attribute:

```
xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine "Application.app"
```

And the app still fails to run. The message reported in the console is:

```
12/11/13 8:28:37.756 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[137]: ([0x0-0x37037].com.company.application[335]) Exited with code: 1
```

It seems this message is usually quarantine / Gatekeeper related. What other cause could there be? What have I overlooked?

Comment: You want to make it much clearer there's a huge difference between removing quarantine from your own known-good app, vs removing quarantine from other apps downloaded from unknown, possibly insecure or malicious sites. The former should be harmless (assuming people have verified your app and company are trustworthy) but the latter could be very dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our app was crashing very early in it's launch cycle, which caused this problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the answer to the question; the issue was not quarantine related. The app was simply crashing very early in it's launch cycle and this is how it manifested.

Comment: You want to make it much clearer there's a huge difference between removing quarantine from your own known-good app, vs removing quarantine from other apps downloaded from unknown, possibly insecure or malicious sites. The former should be harmless (assuming people have verified your app and company are trustworthy) but the latter could be very dangerous.